# Web Browser keywords to automaticly redirect to local websites?

Tags: networking, web-server, web, locale

I have set up a website on my raspberry pi for our local network. My parents are gonna be using it too so I want when they type for example "picam" in the browser that they get directed to the IP address.
Our router is a Fritz! Box 4040 DH and a good example for what I want is: when you type "fritz.box" in the browser you get redirected to the local website of the router.

Is there a way to do this with my pi, that I get automatically to the IP address? If you have questions any questions please ask.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could use a Python web-browser and edit the part where it loads a URL, for example, if a keyword is used, like this: https://github.com/gort818/Roksolana-WebBrowser Editing the code to handle keywords shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution with mDNS. The website I used is the following: https://www.howtogeek.com/167190/how-and-why-to-assign-the-.local-domain-to-your-raspberry-pi/
It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Hello. As you've answered your own question you can also mark it as an accepted solution.

Comment: I can do this only after 2 days.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.